# Which one is better between pure data class and a normal class with business logic in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Code A, I define two standard data calss, but I think that this code just like `aBluetoothDef?.let{BluetoothHelper(mContext).setBluetooth(it)}` is too difficult to extend.

In Code B, I add function for data class, I don't know whether there is a good way to add function to a data class, but I can use the same way such as `aBluetoothDef?.set(mContext)` for extension.

Could you tell me which one is better between Code A and Code B ?

And more, I think that Code B mix data and business logic into a big class, it's not a good way,right?

**Code A**

```
class BluetoothHelper(val mContext: Context) {
   fun setBluetooth(aBluetoothDef: BluetoothDef): Unit{
   }
}

class WiFiHelper(val mContext: Context) {
   fun setWiFi(aWiFiDef: WiFiDef): Unit{
   }
}


interface DeviceDef

data class BluetoothDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef

data class WiFiDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val name: String,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef 


private fun restoreBackup(){   
   var aMDetail=DetailsHandler().getDetail(mListBackupItem[index]._id)

   var aBluetoothDef= aMDetail?.getDevice<BluetoothDef>()
   var aWiFiDef=aMDetail?.getDevice<WiFiDef>()

   aBluetoothDef?.let{BluetoothHelper(mContext).setBluetooth(it)}
   aWiFiDef?.let { WiFiHelper(mContext).setWiFi(it) }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class BluetoothHelper(val mContext: Context) {
   fun setBluetooth(aBluetoothDef: BluetoothDef): Unit{
   }
}

class WiFiHelper(val mContext: Context) {
   fun setWiFi(aWiFiDef: WiFiDef): Unit{
   }
}


interface DeviceDef

data class BluetoothDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef{
   fun set(mContext: Context){
        BluetoothHelper(mContext).setBluetooth(this)
   }
}

data class WiFiDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val name: String,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef {
    fun set(mContext: Context){
        WiFiHelper(mContext).setWiFi(this)
    }
}


private fun restoreBackup(){   
   var aMDetail=DetailsHandler().getDetail(mListBackupItem[index]._id)

   var aBluetoothDef= aMDetail?.getDevice<BluetoothDef>()
   var aWiFiDef=aMDetail?.getDevice<WiFiDef>()

    aBluetoothDef?.set(mContext)
    aBluetoothDef?.set(mContext)
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `let` to check if a value is null like that.`?.let {}` is often mistakenly used when the more readable version, `if (aBluetoothDef == null) BluetoothHelper(mContext).setBluetooth(it)` works just fine.

Comment: For your example code, I think there's a number of improvements and changes that are higher priority than deciding between a pure data class or one with a function. I would recommend not going with either Code A or Code B since they both need review. You could try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically speaking `set()` is not the best naming for what you're actually doing. Since *Kotlin* supports extension functions, you can have both of the approaches at once.

```
data class BluetoothDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef

fun BluetoothDef.with(context: Context) {
    BluetoothHelper(context).setBluetooth(this)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like:

```
private fun restoreBackup(){   

    val deviceService = DeviceService(context);

    val aMDetail=DetailsHandler().getDetail(mListBackupItem[index]._id)

    deviceService.updateBluetooth(aMDetail.getDeviceDefinition<BluetoothDef>());
    deviceService.updateWifi(aMDetail.getDeviceDefinition<WifiDef>())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don`t understand your question. But I think this may be better structure for your class.

```html
class DeviceHelper(){
    var deviceDef = DeviceDef()
}


data class DeviceDef(val isChecked: Boolean = true,
                     val status: Boolean = false,
                     val isWifi: Boolean = false, //if true Wifi else Bluetooth
                     val name: String = "" //Bluetooth and Wireless both have name )


private fun restoreBackup(){
    //Your calculation
}
```